# Extracting roots from a brentq optimization into a numpy array

Tags: python, loops, optimization

```
Sarray = np.arange(0,497,1)

for S in Sarray:
    def f(sigma):
        return ((1/kt)*np.sqrt((sigma**2)+(sigma*E*((sigma/H)**(1/n))))-S)
    Stress = optimize.brentq(f, 0, 10000, args=(), xtol=1e-10, maxiter=100, full_output=True, disp=True)
    print(Stress)
```

I would like to convert the results of this brentq optimization into an array. Right now I only have results in the form:

```
(0.0,       converged: True
           flag: 'converged'
 function_calls: 2
     iterations: 0
           root: 0.0)
(2.42,       converged: True
           flag: 'converged'
 function_calls: 5
     iterations: 4
           root: 2.42)
(4.840000000024723,       converged: True
           flag: 'converged'
 function_calls: 9
     iterations: 8
           root: 4.840000000024723)
```

and so on. Any thoughts on how I can extract the root from each iteration and put it into a numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the parameters full_output to False? It will only return the root
append your Stress to an array then

Comment: Thank you! this worked to create a list of values, but how do I append it into an array?

Comment: either you can create a res = [] before the loop and then res.append(Stress) each iteration, and finally result = np.array(res). Or result = np.array([]) and then result = np.append(result, Stress)